# Whats the correct way of associating more data with a Select Option than just "value"

Tags: javascript, php, html, jsp, html4

I need my  to have more data attached to it. more than just the value attribute.

Right now I am giving `option` fake attributes and and giving them a value. How I think this is not a good way of doing it.

Is there another way?

eg pseudo code

```
<forEach ...>
    <option value="1" userId="4" somespecialCode="c11" ... > 
         Description </option>
<end forEach>
```

edit:
I need to support IE7+

Answer (score 4):

You can use HTML5 [data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/):

```
<option value="1" data-userId="4" data-somespecialCode="c11" ... >
```

That makes your HTML valid (assuming you're using `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your page). Another option is having a JavaScript object with the data, indexed by option value.

Comment: _valid_, assumes HTML5 DOCTYPE, no?

Comment: @user1 sure, but it works equally well in browsers assuming HTML4. Thus, it works and will never break. I'd call that "valid enough".

Comment: @JanDvorak _will never break_ is a pretty brash assumption. There's a reason HTML validators exist, otherwise pages would be tested against browsers and be considered "valid enough". http://validator.w3.org/docs/why.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at HTML 5 data attributes.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/

```
<forEach ...>
    <option value="1" userId="4" data-somespecialCode="c11" ... > 
         Description </option>
<end forEach>
```